# Algorithm: fill table with obstacles

Tags: javascript, algorithm, logic

I'm making a simple game with Javascript:
a table (in this case 6x6) with some random obstacles,
we have to start from a point and move around trying to fill all the table

In this example there are three obstacles, and if we try some different route there are ALWAYS three missing blocks that we can't fill.

Is there a mathematical theorem or an algorithm that can solve this problem?
Why can't we fill all the table? How to place obstacles to avoid this?

[image: Example of table with some different routes]

Comment: There might **not** be a solution that fills every block. You're looking for a [Hamiltonian Path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path), and determining if one exists for a given graph is NP-complete. However, for a 6x6 grid you should be able to do a depth-first search until you find a path that visits all of the blocks or exhausts all possible paths.

Comment: We could possibly think of this as a topological problem. We have a "snake" that's 33 square-units long, which needs to envelope (or otherwise coexist with) 3 individual square-units. And what are the different ways it can be displayed boxed into 6x6.